# How do you set a default valut to input type = date with c# MVC

Tags: c#, html

I have a simple date field that i want to populate with a value from my database so my users can see the default before they edit:

```
<input type = "date" name = "Date" style = "width:180px;" value="@ViewBag.Options.Date"/>
```

Simply put, this doesnt popluate the date input. it works on all other forms of html5 inputs however, also worth noting that the `ViewBag.Options.Date` is a `DateTime` variable.

Comment: Do you have some code & markup we can look at?

Comment: @Stephen sorry code block wasnt formated properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your date needs to have a specific formatting to make it unambiguous:

```
@ViewBag.Options.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

For every HTML input field, the browser will leave it empty unless a default value is specified with the value attribute.

currently HTML5 doesn't provide any way of specifying default date in the value attribute.

try some script may be it helps.